# how to make all points show in reveal plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

It's very general question but I still have no good solution how to solve it as my first idea is editing plugin which is I guess wrong, that's the screenshot
[image]

in this image you see a lot of points, the thing is, all points should be shown. Does anyone have better solution than doctoring around directly in the plugin, which might in worst case break the plugin completely?

Comment: 1.  It's not a good idea to update a plugin directly.  When the plugin is updated, your customization will be deleted. 

2.  My guess is that this is a default setting with the embedded map and you likely won't be able to edit it from the plugin.